# netsnmp - How to get the size-constraints of a column in net-snmp?

Tags: perl, snmp, mib

Suppose I have the following code in mib2c.conf:

```
@foreach $t table@ 
    Starting table $t
    @foreach $c column@
       echo $t has column $c which has a syntax of $c.syntax
       ...
    @end@
@end@ EOF
```

How can I get the size-related constraints for column `$c` from the MIB file (min/max value for integers or list of accepted values for enums).
I would like to feed these values to netsnmp_chech_vb_XXXX in order to validate some SNMP set requests, but I am not sure how to get them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the mib2c code you'll see the comment below:

```
#   @foreach $RANGE_START, $RANGE_END range NODE@
#     repeat iterate over code until @end@ setting $RANGE_START and $RANGE_END
#     to the legal accepted range set for a given mib NODE.
```

You'll note that you need to iterate over the ranges.  Integers and sizes don't just have a single range much of the time.  IE, it's legal to have an integer that must be from 2-4 or from 6-8 with a blank in the middle.  The above code will let you loop through every range set.

Comment: can you give me an example? How do I know which range corresponds to my column?

Comment: I tried that and it kind of worked.....$RANGE_START is always "" ($RANGE_END works). Any ideas?

Comment: Turns out the comment is wrong (which I'll go fix).  There shouldn't be a comma.  IE, try: @foreach $RANGE_START $RANGE_END range NODE@